# Drop index if name like

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to find a way to drop multiple indexes from various tables with a single query in SQL Server. I can find the index name and table by using the query below, but I'm a bit lost on how I should go about dropping the tables it finds.

```
SELECT
            so.name AS TableName
            , si.name AS IndexName
            , si.type_desc AS IndexType
FROM
            sys.indexes si
            JOIN sys.objects so ON si.[object_id] = so.[object_id]
WHERE
            so.type = 'U'    --Only get indexes for User Created Tables
            AND si.name IS NOT NULL
            and si.name like 'NCI%'
ORDER BY
            so.name, si.type
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can construct your drop script starting from your `SELECT`:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'DROP INDEX ' + so.name + '.' + si.name + ';' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM
            sys.indexes si
            JOIN sys.objects so ON si.[object_id] = so.[object_id]
WHERE
            so.type = 'U'    --Only get indexes for User Created Tables
            AND si.name IS NOT NULL
            and si.name like '%%'
ORDER BY
            so.name, si.type 

PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

`@SQL` is built incrementally and will contain all `DROP` statements separated by `;` so that they execute in a single batch. `DROP`ing tables can be done in a similar manner.

NOTE: your query also catches indexes associated to `PK`s and they cannot be dropped directly, as they are doubled by a constraint (PK = constraint + index)

Comment: Well done. I was just about an almost identical solution. The cursor solutions work too but I just hate them with a passion. :)

Comment: Yes, I also do not like them. I think that SQL is about set based operations an iterative constructs do not belong here :D.

Comment: @Alexei: It's worth mentioning that this is not a set based solution either; it's a row by row iteration to assemble the command at the end.  For my taste, it feels a bit too dependent on a side effect, but it's valid and it works.  Just because there's no cursor doesn't mean the solution is set-based.

Comment: @DaveMarkle - yes, that's correct. However, I expect to be a little faster that using the cursor (and also much easier to write and understand).

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those times in life you generally will want to use a cursor, because your statement is dynamic.

```
DECLARE drop_cur cursor for 
SELECT
            QUOTENAME(so.name) AS TableName,
            QUOTENAME(si.name) AS IndexName,
            si.type_desc AS IndexType
FROM
            sys.indexes si
            JOIN sys.objects so ON si.[object_id] = so.[object_id]
WHERE
            so.type = 'U'    --Only get indexes for User Created Tables
            AND si.name IS NOT NULL
            and si.name like 'NCI%'
ORDER BY
            so.name, si.type 

OPEN drop_cur
DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(MAX), @indexname NVARCHAR(MAX), @indextype NVARCHAR(MAX);

FETCH NEXT FROM drop_cur INTO @tableName, @indexName, @indextype
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 BEGIN    
    DECLARE @dropSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'drop index ' + @tablename + '.' + @indexname
    PRINT @dropSql
    --EXEC sp_executesql @dropSql --Uncomment to perform the drop.
    FETCH NEXT FROM drop_cur INTO @tableName, @indexName, @indextype
END 

CLOSE drop_cur
DEALLOCATE drop_cur
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tabName sysname
declare @ixName sysname
declare @sql varchar(1000)  --Probably don't need it, but meh.

declare cur_dels cursor for
SELECT
            so.name AS TableName
            , si.name AS IndexName
--            , si.type_desc AS IndexType
FROM
            sys.indexes si
            JOIN sys.objects so ON si.[object_id] = so.[object_id]
WHERE
            so.type = 'U'    --Only get indexes for User Created Tables
            AND si.name IS NOT NULL
            and si.name like 'NCI%'
ORDER BY
            so.name, si.type 

open cur_dels
fetch next from cur_dels into @tabName, @ixName

while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        set @sql = 'alter table ' + @tabName + ' drop ' + @ixName + ';'
        print @sql
        --exec sp_executesql @sql
        fetch next from cur_dels into @tabName, @ixName
    end

close cur_dels
deallocate cur_dels
```

Obviously, if you want to just run it w/o seeing what's happening, un-rem the exec statement in the loop & rem out the print statement.  If you want to review it, though (which ... well, I'd do, rather than letting this free by itself), leave as is.